# Passing a objects from a vector to another class

Tags: c++, vector

I have 3 classes:

```
class User{
}

class Main{
public:
   void AddClash(){
       clash.push(Clash(...))
   }
private:
   std::vector<User> users;
   std::vector<Clash> clash;
}

class Clash{
public:
   //constructor
private:
   std::array<...,2> users;
}
```

I would like to have a method in the `Main` class, which will create a `Clash` object with a field that points to two objects from `std::vector` `users` in `Main` class.

What is the proper way to do that (pointer, std::reference_wrapper, std::shared_ptr, ...)?

Comment: You could either have `vector<shared_ptr<User>>`,  or you could refer to the users in some other way (e.g. a user id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to face the problem that `std::vector` displaces its content when it needs to grow, invalidating any pointer, reference or iterator in the process.

Thus, unless you know for sure that nothing will be pushed into your `users` vector while the `Clash`es are alive, you need to either :

- Keep an index (`std::size_t`)into the vector. But you'll also need a reference to the vector itself, so you can access you object via `vec[idx]`.
- Add an indirection : make `users` an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<User>>` (or `shared_ptr`, depending on your design). Then the `User` objects themselves won't ever move around.